# How to install packages with pip to python 2 when python 3 is the "default"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am using python 3 but, for a course I am taking I need to use python 2. So I installed it. Now I need to install a package called zmq. Before I just installed it by doing `pip install zmq` but how do I install this package to python 2?

Comment: `pip install` installs Python 2 dependencies. `pip3 install` installs Python 3 dependencies.

Comment: @erip When I installed if for the first time, I didnt have python 2. And now if I do `pip install zmq` It says `Requirement already satisfied`, and shows the path for python 3

Comment: @FelixRosén Try using `pip2` or `pip2.7` instead of `pip`. That should point to the python 2 packages.

Comment: @Munir pip2 or pip2.7 is not recognized. I think It could have something to do with my path maybe. Should I define the path in user or system variables?

Comment: @FelixRosén Which OS are you on? On Linux/Unix systems, `pip2` is probably in `/usr/local/bin`. On Windows, you'll need to find `pip2` and then change to that directory and call it. Don't know if there is something special for Mac.

Comment: I am using windows 7. I got it to work by doing: `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`. It would be much easier to simoy do `pip2`. Could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally pip installs not only the `pip` command but also the `pip2` and `pip2.7` command in your Path.

So, to install within the Python 2 context use:

```
pip2 install <package>
```

And to install within the Python 3 context use:

```
pip3 install <package>
```

Comment: So, it seems like my pip path points to another directory then where I want it. Do you know how to change this? Because now I can only do `pip`.  `pip2` or `pip2.7` are not recognized.

Comment: @FelixRosén: in that case you need to add the Python bin directory to your `PATH` environment variable